# Autocomplete not working in Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-dialog

Hi I have an AutoComplete on an input field. It works fine when called from a HTML view but when called using a Dialog, the dropdown list does not appear. The data appears in the dropdown if I use up & down keys but I do not see the dropdown. How can I make it work?

Comment: You'll have to provide some more info... for instance: any js error on console?

Comment: Something to consider in using "Selector". When you make your dialog HTML in the `<body>` somewhere, keep in mind, as soon as you call `.dialog` on it, it is "moved". That is to say, jQueryUI builds a fancy wrapper around it and appends it to the body. Thus, if your "Selector" for you're autocomp were something like `$("body #somecontainer .my-auto-c")` && you're dialog was also inside `#somecontainer`, whenever you made dialog into dialog, your original selector would no longer work because it no longer sits in that container.

Comment: Create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net). Showing your code says more than a 1000 words ;)

Comment: @SpYk3HH Probably u r correct. I can see my autocompete dropdown if I disable jquery ui.css. It appears but somehow when I include the css, the body of the dialog comes the foreground and the dropdown goes in the background. I am not sure how to solve this. Let me know your inputs. Thanks

Comment: @user1596433 easiest way to solve it, if you're going to put the autocomplete in a dialog, give that dialog an ID, then do all your selecting for that autocomplete based on the Dialog ID. example: `<div id="myDialog"><input name="myAC" />` then your CSS would be like `#myDialog .ui-autocomplete-input {` and your jQuery selector would be in the same context: `$("#myDialog input[name=myAC]")` or after ac is set `$("#myDialog .ui-autocomplete-input")` [Keep in mind, jQuery will add the class I show here after autocomplete is initialized.

Answer (score 6):

I had to change the z-index of autocomplete in order to make it work. I added the below code in my css:

```
.ui-autocomplete
    {
        position:absolute;
        cursor:default;
        z-index:4000 !important
    }
```

Comment: This solution works, but it's not the best way to do it, and can be troublesome. You'd rather use the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

By default the dropdown is a div element which is attached to the body. As the body has a lower z-index than your modal dialog, the dropdown isn't visible.

To solve this you have to attach it to an element inside the dialog. You can do it in two ways:

- specify the `appendTo` option and refer to an element inside your dialog
- add the `'ui-front'` class to an element which contains your autocomplete input and it's inside the dialog

In this way the dropdown div element will have the same z-index than the dialog and it will show up without problem.

I.e., if you have this:

```
<div id='myDialog'>
  <input id='myAutocompleteInput'>
```

You have to add the class like this:

```
<div id='myDialog' class='ui-front'>
  <input id='myAutocompleteInput'>
```

or specify the append to option in your autocomplete

```
$('#myAutocompleteInput').autocomplete({
  appendTo: '#myDialog'
  // ...
})
```

Reference: [jquery UI dialog appendTo option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo).

Comment: I thought the `appendTo` was which element the dropdown should be appended to and thus I set my `appendTo` to the input with the autocomplete (which doesn't work for me). But setting the `appendTo` to point at my dialog (which contains the autocomplete input deep down) like you do in your example works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have more than one selector with the same ID o class.

Comment: then in that case it should not work when calling outside of dialog.